# Matlab: How to delete folder based on their date? (e.g. 3 oldest ones in a directory)

Tags: matlab, directory, delete-file

I am wondering how I can make an automatic deleting process in matlab, and even is it possible or not!

For instance I want to delete let's say the 3 oldest folders in matlab's current directory. But the problem is that the 3 oldest folders might come out based on the date they have been saved, or the hour. The comparison varies, it might come into hour comparison or day comparison.

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function returns the specified number of oldest directories of the given directory. It uses the [dir](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command to list the directory contents, sorts the structure based on the "datenum" field, then returns the oldest directories:

```
function oldestDirs = getOldestDirectories(directory, count)
oldestDirs = {};
if ~isdir(directory) || count <= 0
    return;
end

directories = dir(directory);

fields = fieldnames(directories);
dirCell = struct2cell(directories);
sz = size(dirCell);

% Convert to a matrix
dirCell = reshape(dirCell, sz(1), []);

% Make each field a column
dirCell = dirCell';

% Sort by first field "name"
dirCell = sortrows(dirCell, find(ismember(fields, 'datenum')));

% Put back into original cell array format
dirCell = reshape(dirCell', sz);

% Convert to Struct
sorted = cell2struct(dirCell, fields, 1);

foundElems = 0;
for i = numel(sorted):-1:1
    if sorted(i).isdir && ~any(strcmp(sorted(i).name, {'.', '..'}))
        foundElems = foundElems + 1;
        oldestDirs{foundElems} = fullfile(directory, sorted(i).name);
    end
    if foundElems == count
        return;
    end
end
end
```

You can use it like:

```
oldDirs = getOldestDirectories(cd(), 3);
```

Then you can simply remove the directories in a loop:

```
for i = 1:numel(oldDirs), rmdir(oldDirs{i}, 's'); end
```